# How to use sortable data structure in redis

Tags: php, database, redis, database-schema

How to store and retrieve data-structure like this in redis in most efficient way. The record will be accessed by **username value** which will be unique and we need to **sort data** by **date** and **counter** values.

[image: redis data structure]

Also, is **redis** the best choice for this scenario (performance takes precedence here over everything).

Comment: If performance takes precedence over everything, you should probably not be using PHP.

Comment: @Oswald what other alternative do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted sets sort items automatically based on a `score` value, which can be any string-based value for double precision floating point number. You can also use [SORT](http://redis.io/commands/sort) command which does on-the-fly sorting for lists and sets.

Going back to sorted sets, you can sort by date using using long timestamps:

```
ZADD uniqueName 13733654484 stringData1 197625203673 stringData2
```

Or you can sort by counter:

```
ZADD uniqueName 100 stringData1 101 stringData2
```

That's one way to do it.

Comment: SORT performs on-demand sorting; it's not natural sorting embedded within the data structure. But fair enough, I've updated my answer. How can you sort on both values? Can you show an example?

Comment: I did not try the SORT command but used the ZINTERSTORE instead: zinterstore tmp 2 nameByDate nameByCounter WEIGHTS 1 2. That way you are able to sort the data by counter AND date (using weights). Oh and  don't forget that the score must be first with ZADD. E.g. ZADD uniqueName 13733654484 stringData1 197625203673 stringData2.